# Почему не корректно срабатывает ZBuffer

Tags: c++, opengl

Помогите, уже второй день не могу понять, почему у меня не корректно отображается 3d сцена, плоскости не перекрываются, почему, не понятно

```
class Camera {
public:
    glm::quat camera_quat;
    GLfloat x = 0.5, y = 6.5, z = -60;
    GLfloat centerx = 0.5, centery = 0, centerz = 1;
    GLfloat rotx = 1, roty = 0, rotz = 0;
};

struct point3d {
    float x, y, z;
};

class Scene {
public:
    Camera* camera = new Camera();
};

float speedx = 0;

struct coordinate {
    float x, y, z;
    coordinate(float a, float b, float c) : x(a), y(b), z(c) {};
};

float angle = 0.0;      

Scene* scene = new Scene();

std::vector <Object3D>* objects3D = new std::vector < Object3D>();

float offset = 0;
bool loaded = false;

void display(void)
{
    if (!loaded) {
        loader.LoadFile("map3.obj", objects3D);
        loaded = true;
    }

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();


    int height = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    int width = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
    gluPerspective(60.0f, (double)width / (double)height, 0.0f, 300.0f);


    glm::mat4 myMatrix;
    glm::vec4 myVector;

    float key_pitch = 5, key_yaw = 0, key_roll = 0;

    glm::quat key_quat = glm::quat(glm::vec3(key_pitch, key_yaw, key_roll));

    key_pitch = key_yaw = key_roll = 0;

    scene->camera->camera_quat = key_quat * scene->camera->camera_quat;
    scene->camera->camera_quat = glm::normalize(scene->camera->camera_quat);
    glm::mat4 rotate = glm::mat4_cast(scene->camera->camera_quat);

    glm::mat4 translate = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::vec3 eyeVector(0, 0, 0);
    translate = glm::translate(translate, -eyeVector);

    glm::mat4 viewMatrix = rotate * translate;


    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); //СМОТРЕТЬ ОТСЮДА ----------------------------------->
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(scene->camera->x, scene->camera->y, scene->camera->z, scene->camera->x + scene->camera->rotx, scene->camera->y + scene->camera->roty, scene->camera->z + scene->camera->rotz, 0, 1, 0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);

    for (int i = 0; i < objects3D->size(); i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < objects3D->at(i).vertex.size(); k++)
        {
            glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            glColor3d(1, 1, 1);

            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, objects3D->at(i).texture);
            glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

            for (int j = 0; j < objects3D->at(i).vertex.at(k).size(); j++)
            {
                glTexCoord2d(objects3D->at(i).vertex.at(k).at(j).TextureCoordinate.X, objects3D->at(i).vertex.at(k).at(j).TextureCoordinate.Y);
                glVertex3f(objects3D->at(i).vertex.at(k).at(j).Position.X, objects3D->at(i).vertex.at(k).at(j).Position.Y, objects3D->at(i).vertex.at(k).at(j).Position.Z);
            }
            glEnd();
            glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        }
    }

    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);
    glutCreateWindow("game");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Вот сама неправильно отрисованная сцена, ну вы сами видите, например забор за домом правильно отрисовался, а вот окна на задней стороне домика совсем не правильно, они не должны были отрисовываться, что делать? ((((((((

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тест глубины по умолчанию выключен. `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`

Comment: @extrn вот блин, обидно, не помогло (скрин прикрепил) :*(

Comment: Ну вы скорее всего спросите, чищу ли я буффер, я чищу `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);`, а потом только включаю `GL_DEPTH_TEST`

Comment: Что же не так, хоть убей, без Depth_test и без текстур, всё ИДЕАЛЬНО, а как пытаюсь сделать с текстурами, всё хуже, а с zbuffer'ом вообще всё (почти) пропадает

Comment: Спрошу я о другом. Вы правда думаете, что это полотенце кода без начала и конца кто-то кроме вас сможет отладить? :) Ели бы меня попросили угадать, предположил бы, что дело в `gluPerspective`. Границы должны быть строго положительными, например `0.001f, 300.0f`.